# How to using only divs tags and css

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to HTML and CSS so perhaps this is a crazy easy question to answer.

The question is:
How to do this using only divs and css?

I don't want to use `<table> <tr> <th> <td>....`

[image: Header]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic setup of what you're asking using the `flexbox` property.

> The **CSS3 Flexible Box**, or `flexbox`, is a layout mode providing for the
>   arrangement of elements on a page such that the elements behave
>   predictably when the page layout must accommodate different screen
>   sizes and different display devices. For many applications, the
>   flexible box model provides an improvement over the block model in
>   that it does not use floats, nor do the flex container's margins
>   collapse with the margins of its contents.

Read more about it [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) and experiment with it so you feel comfortable using it. The setup might not be pixel perfect, but it gives you a good start for the desired layout. Trial and error, that's the best way to learn.

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.middle {
  flex-basis: 200%;
}

.middle-top,
.right-top,
.right-bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.language,
.search,
.login,
.signup,
.some-text,
.avatar {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="column left">
    <div class="social">
      Social icons
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      Logo
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column middle">
    <div class="middle-top">
      <div class="language">
        Language
      </div>
      <div class="search">
        Search
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slogan">
      Slogan
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      Menu
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column right">
    <div class="right-top">
      <div class="login">
        Login
      </div>
      <div class="signup">
        Signup
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-middle">
      Welcome guest
    </div>
    <div class="right-bottom">
      <div class="some-text">
        <div class="something">
          Some text
        </div>
        <div class="something">
          Some text
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="avatar">
        Avatar
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh...... thanks Roy. Now i got an idea. main mistake i made, was playing with floating. Thanks again mate...

Comment: @AlgirdasDabašinskas If the solution helped, please mark it as answer, so this question can be 'closed'.